# Using Tomcat and JSP files won't compile

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Hello I'm using Eclipse Indigo and trying to run Tomcat version 4.1. For some reason Tomcat wont compile my JSP files and I'm completely lost as to why they wont compile. I've had my co workers look at it but so far nothing has helped.

I was wondering if anyone had an idea of what settings I should look at and how I should change it so that there is some progress made? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Add some useful information, e.g. a meaningful explanation of what "For some reason Tomcat wont compile my JSP files" really means.

Comment: 4.1 must be run with a full JDK since it has no Java compiler of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 4.1 is a very old version, indeed.  Current production is Tomcat 7.  I'd recommend an immediate upgrade.

http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Which JVM version are you trying run under?

My first guess is that your JSPs don't match the servlet/JSP spec version supported by Tomcat.  Synch up the JARs and XML configuration to match.

It would help to provide stack traces, error messages, so something more tangible than "won't compile".

Comment: yeah I know we should upgrade but that's what they are using,

Comment: Which JVM?  "Should upgrade" ought to read "must upgrade".  Match your JSPs to the version you're running, if you can.